# java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry during packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library, android-multidex

I am not sure what this error means.

```
Execution failed for task ':excelSior:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/util/TimeUtils.class
```

I am currently using `android-support-v4.jar` for my libraries

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':addThisSDK')
    compile project(':centeredContentButton')
    compile project(':googleplayservices_lib')
    compile files('libs/adxtag2.4.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    compile files('libs/aws-android-sdk-1.7.1.1-debug.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-lang-2.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/crittercism_v4_4_0_sdkonly.jar')
    compile files('libs/dd-plist.jar')
    compile files('libs/FiksuAndroidSDK_4.1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/iqengines-sdk-barcode.jar')
    compile files('libs/irEventTracker-1.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/jolt-core-0.0.7.jar')
    compile files('libs/json-utils-0.0.7.jar')
    compile files('libs/jsoup-1.7.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/kooaba-api-v4-java.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

Error does not show up during gradle sync. Just when I try to run the application

What could be the problem?

Comment: The error comes when  any other jar dependency of yours have same class, make sure you have not added support jar both as gradle and jar dependency. please include complete dependency closure in the question.

Comment: @pyus13 thanks. I have updated the question. This is my whole dependency list

Comment: You have 3 module dependencies in your project, so make sure only one of all them have the support-v4 as dependency.

Comment: please see my answer at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28168063/gradle-duplicate-entry-java-util-zip-zipexception/28937822#28937822

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':Mulugu Astro:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/view/ViewPager$MyAccessibilityDelegate.class

Comment: how to solve this error please help me

Comment: in my libs am having support-v4.jar

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You need to check that you have inserted v4 library and compile library?  You must not repeat library in your app or your dependence program.

delete the repeat library so that just one V4 remains.

in your app dir `build.gradle` file
add this command:

```
android{


    configurations {
        all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }

}
```

it works for me!  You can try it!

Comment: After adding this fragments cant get support of v4, Any idea?

Comment: @Nisarg also happens to me.

Comment: @Nisarg    you can use gradle recompile the program.

Comment: @NisargCan you please help me how to recompile again, I too have the same problem as yours, fragments and taskstackbuilder have stopped resolving

Answer (score 81):

You've probably fixed this by now but just so this doesn't stay unanswered,
Try adding this to your `build.gradle`:

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
```

Comment: I have added the configurations line but still `Error:Execution failed for task ':Analyst:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/android/vending/billing/IInAppBillingService$Stub$Proxy.class` it shows.

Comment: How did you fix the issue?

Comment: is there any right solution.i am getting same problem  java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/gson/annotations/Expose.class

Comment: Error:(5, 30) error: package android.support.v4.app does not exist 

Getting this error after adding your answer

Comment: I'm getting this error after adding the configuration in my build.gradle
Error:(29, 0) Cannot change configuration ':app:_debugApk' after it has been resolved.

Comment: Where is this supposed to go, I'm new to gradle and there are 5 build.gradle files in my current project, none of them have `configurations` in them and it doesn't seem to matter where I put it, I get errors like cannot resolve symbol 'exclude' or cannot resolve symbol 'all'

Comment: i am having the same issue **Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/apache/xmlbeans/xml/stream/Location.class** how to fix this i am using android studio @hardartcore

Comment: This does not seem to work on AS 1.5  
 
I get the message cannot resolve symbol 'exclude'

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.transform.api.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/multidex/MultiDex$V14.class

Comment: my issue is fixed on higher version but on 2.3 i got same error .

Comment: For Gson Exponse.class error use this                                                         `configurations {
        all*.exclude  module: 'gson'
    }`

Comment: Although this fixed that issue, it meant that any of my code that referenced the `support-v4` library could not resolve. So, use this with care because it's not an ideal solution, it just remove that library entirely from your library dependency compilation.

Answer (score 25):

I also came across this kind issue when re import old eclipse project. It occurred some old dependency as jar file in the project.

just remove

> compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')

in gradle file

and add dependency in the gradle file.

It works for me ..

Comment: This error occurred when import old eclipse project  
sorry,, actually, i removed some of the reference library and add same dependency in gradle file.

Comment: Worked for me (also importing from old eclipse configuration). After that clean and rebuild was required.

Comment: Why should I trust one named Sauron?

Comment: Stopped this specific error, but caused dozens of others.  Sometimes you need those dependencies.  As strange as this may sound, Sauron was right this time.

Comment: you definitely need those dependencies. but my case if i inject those dependencies using lib (manual download), it ll be caused this issue. After that I add those dependencies  using 'compile <lib>' . I think most of the time, repeated library caused this issue. so you can exclude those lib. I hope this may helpful.

Comment: By adding your dependencies explicitly, one by one, you'll likely uncover a duplicate `.jar` library that you're including twice. Never use `compile fileTree(...)`, it hides too many obvious errors.

Answer (score 13):

In my case the mentioned "duplicate entry" error arised after setting`multiDexEnable=true` in the build.gradle.

In order to fully resolve the error first of all have a look at [Configure Apps with Over 64K Methods](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html) (espescially "Configuring Your App for Multidex with Gradle").

Furthermore search for occurences of the class that causes the "duplicate entry" error using ctrl+n in Android Studio. Determine the module and dependency that contains the duplicate and exclude it from build, e.g.:

```
compile ('org.roboguice:roboguice:2.0') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
```

I had to try multiple module labels till it worked. Excluding "support-v4" solves issues related to "java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/*"

Answer (score 9):

My understanding is that there are duplicate references to the same API (Likely different version numbers). It should be reasonably easy to debug when building from the command line.

Try `./gradlew yourBuildVariantName --debug` from the command line.

The offending item will be the first failure. An example might look like:

```
14:32:29.171 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Task] INPUT: /Users/mydir/Documents/androidApp/BaseApp/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/theOffendingAAR/libs/google-play-services.jar

14:32:29.171 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Finished executing task ':BaseApp:packageAllyourBuildVariantNameClassesForMultiDex'

14:32:29.172 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.TaskExecutionLogger] :BaseApp:packageAllyourBuildVariantNameClassesForMultiDex FAILED'
```

In the case above, the aar file that I'd included in my libs directory (theOffendingAAR) included the Google Play Services jar (yes the whole thing. yes I know.) file whilst my BaseApp build file utilised location services:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:6.5.87'
```

You can safely remove the offending item from your build file(s), clean and rebuild (repeat if necessary).

Comment: So what if I need the offending library?

Comment: This helped me track down the offending library :)

Comment: This doesnt help..on removing the offending library  the module fails to compile

Answer (score 9):

check your dependencies versions, you must have compatible versions put attention specially to com.google packages, must have same version like:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.3.0'
```

Both are 8.3.0, if you have another version compilation will throw that exception.

Comment: Thanks Man, Working perfect, I have three different google play services compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.4.0'

Answer (score 5):

Simple Remove Your Jar file from dependencies gardle.project as v7 
and run your project

Comment: That's work for me, simply remove "compile files('libs/android-support-v13.jar')" form "dependencies" in my "build.gradle (Module: app)". For reference y get this error after import project form eclipse to Android Studio.

Answer (score 5):

For Expose.class Error i.e

java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/gson/annotations/Expose.class

use the below code

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude  module: 'gson'
}
```

Comment: The OP said nothing about `gson`.

Answer (score 3):

find out the lib depends on the support v4, and exclude it.

code in `build.gradle` is like this:

```
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.1') {
    // http://stackoverflow.com/a/30931887/5210
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
}
```

In my situation, the lib 'espresso' has a jar called support-v4 and in my project 'app' have the same support-v4, exclude the support-v4 when import espresso.

PS: it seems `compile project` can not work with the `exclude`

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have added a library and given its dependency on a module more than once.

In my case, I had added a library as a module and as a gradle dependency both.

Removing one source of adding library (I removed gradle dependency) solved my problem.

Comment: alternatively, this issue was fixed for me by removing the jar from the libs dir and keeping the gradle dependency.

Comment: Yeh! Removing any single source will do the issue. Keeping gradle dependence is good.

Answer (score 0):

For Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug' com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException java.util.zip.ZipException duplicate entry com/google/gson/annotations/Expose.class

Here is what I did:

1) Delete the gson-2.5.jar file.
2) configurations { all*.exclude module: 'gson-2.5' }

Comment: Question wasn't about Gson

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue as i have manually copied the jar in libs as well as mentioned the dependency in gradle file. You also check in your project structure, whether the same jar file is copied in any other folder like libs or in project folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after upgrading the android SDK. I was able to run the application in the `buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'`, I got the same error when I changed to `buildToolsVersion '24.0.3'`

I resolved the problem by updating my java version from 1.7 to 1.8 with `compileSdkVersion 24`

Answer (score 0):

This problem cost me one whole day. I finally downgraded the firebase-ui library version from 2.0.0 to 1.2.0 and added the following code inside Project level build.gradle file:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()

        // Add the following code to your project level build.gradle
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Firebase UI version depends on what version of Firebase you actually compiled

Answer (score 0):

I also have the issue because of i have  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0-alpha1' but i added recyclerview liberary compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.0.2'..i changed the version as same as compat like (24.0.2 intead of 24.0.0).

i got the answer..may be it will help for someone.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the mentioned "duplicate entry" error arised after settingmultiDexEnable=true in the build.gradle.

and exact error which i was getting was below :

```
Error:Execution failed for task 
':android:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: 
java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: 
com/google/android/gms/internal/zzqx.class
```

So first thing I search for class which causes "duplicate entry" error using ctrl+n in Android Studio and searched for com/google/android/gms/internal/zzqx.class and then it was showing 2 entries for gms class with one version 8.4.0 and 1 with version 11.6.0 .

To fix it i made both to use 11.6.0 and it was fixed example

earlier

```
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:11.6.0"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.4.0"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.6.0"
```

After

```
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:11.6.0"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.0"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.6.0"
```

Rebuilding Fixed .

Answer (score 0):

In my case exact error was below

':android:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzqx.class

I was using another version of google apis i.e. in one modules gradle file

```
if (!project.hasProperty('gms_library_version')) {
        ext.gms_library_version = '8.6.0'
   }
```

however in other modules version 11.6.0 as below

```
   compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.6.0"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:11.6.0"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.0"
```

However to find this i did a ctrl + n in android studio and entered class name zzqx.class and then it displayed 2 jar files being pulled for this class and then i understood that somewhere i am using version 8.6.0 . On changing 8.6.0 to 11.6.0 and rebuilding the project the issue was fixed .

Hope this helps .

More on this here 
https://www.versionpb.com/tutorials/step-step-tutorials-libgdx-basic-setup-libgdx/implementing-google-play-services-leaderboards-in-libgdx/

Answer (score 0):

For me something similar happened when I had accidently added

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
```

to my android library module. Removing the line fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the above solutions but not working for me. I tried update libraries by goto project structure > app. And it works for me! Hope this answer helpful to someone.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
android {
configurations {
        all*.exclude  module: 'PhotoView'  //去除重复依赖库
    }
}
```

Comment: This question is about the support v4 library, not PhotoView