# How to click on an item inside a RecyclerView in Espresso

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-espresso

I have a RecyclerView (R.id.recyclerView) where each row has an image (R.id.row_image) and a TextView. I want to click on the image in the first row.
I've tried to use onData(..) but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 88):

Use [RecyclerViewActions](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/espresso/contrib/RecyclerViewActions?hl=en#actiononitematposition)

```
onView(withId(R.id.recyclerView))
    .perform(actionOnItemAtPosition(0, click()));
```

Include this in your gradle script:

```
dependencies {
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.0'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.0'
}
```

Comment: I get Test running failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException' when I add espresso-contrib.

Comment: @dannyroa, you should exclude group: 'javax.inject' on it

Comment: so, how do you `check(isDisplayed())` ?

Comment: for folks having @dannyroa's issue, check out jdebon's answer below

Comment: New AndroidX dependencies are described here https://developer.android.com/training/testing/set-up-project

Comment: the dependence androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:testing-support-lib:0.1' is not required to perform a click in a RV, that can cause problem to compile Kotlin Code.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/lists#recycler-view-list-items

refer here for more details

Answer (score 21):

Just to add to Gabor's answer (which is the correct and complete answer since Espresso 2.0).

You may encounter problems at the moment when using `espresso-contrib` and `RecyclerView`s (see [android-test-kit ticket](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/issues/detail?id=157)).

A workaround is to add this exclusion in the `espresso-contrib` dependency Gabor mentioned above:

```
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.0') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
}
```

(This is an answer instead of a comment to Gabor's answer because I don't have the right to post comments yet)

Comment: this helped fix java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError, thanks!

Answer (score 16):

### Edit:

Espresso 2.0 has been released, [the changelog](https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/downloads/release-notes/) includes the following:

> ### New Features
>
> - espresso-contrib
>
>   - RecyclerViewActions: handles interactions with RecyclerViews

---

#### Old Answer

I haven't yet tested this myself, but Thomas Keller [posted this](https://plus.google.com/+ThomasKeller1/posts/UnEVcQim5jQ) on G+ with a short explanation and a link to a Gist with the necessary view matchers.

> Since the new `RecyclerView` API inherits from `ViewGroup` and not from `AdapterView`, you cannot use Espresso's `onData()` to test layouts using this component.

[Link to Gist](https://gist.github.com/tommyd3mdi/2622caecc1b2d498cd1a).

I'll attach the code, just for completeness sake (note: **not mine!** All credit goes to Thomas Keller)

ViewMatcher:

```
public class ViewMatchers {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static Matcher<View> withRecyclerView(@IdRes int viewId) {
        return allOf(isAssignableFrom(RecyclerView.class), withId(viewId));
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static ViewInteraction onRecyclerItemView(@IdRes int identifyingView, Matcher<View> identifyingMatcher, Matcher<View> childMatcher) {
        Matcher<View> itemView = allOf(withParent(withRecyclerView(R.id.start_grid)),
                withChild(allOf(withId(identifyingView), identifyingMatcher)));
        return Espresso.onView(allOf(isDescendantOfA(itemView), childMatcher));
    }
}
```

And sample usage:

```
onRecyclerItemView(R.id.item_title, withText("Test"),  withId(R.id.item_content))
    .matches(check(withText("Test Content")));
```

Answer (score 6):

You should use a Custom ViewAction:

```
public void clickOnImageViewAtRow(int position) {
    onView(withId(R.id.recycler_view)).perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition(position, new ClickOnImageView()));
}

public class ClickOnImageView implements ViewAction{
    ViewAction click = click();

    @Override
    public Matcher<View> getConstraints() {
        return click.getConstraints();
    }

    @Override
    public String getDescription() {
        return " click on custom image view";
    }

    @Override
    public void perform(UiController uiController, View view) {
        click.perform(uiController, view.findViewById(R.id.imageView));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Same answer like above but when some small modification since you have to provide the Viewholder type

With using RecyclerViewActions

```
fun tapOnRecyclerView(@IdRes resId: Int , position: Int) = onView(withId(resId))
        .perform(actionOnItemAtPosition<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(position, click()));
```

and to include this libraries in your project , use this

```
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:$espressoVersion"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:$espressoVersion"
```

Prefer to use the latest espresso version from this [link](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.test.espresso/espresso-core?repo=google)

Answer (score 3):

I have found two ways:

1. Assuming you have a textview with id "R.id.description" for each item in the RecyclerView. You can do this to match a specific child:

`onView(allOf(withId(R.id.place_description),withText("what"))).perform(click());`

2. A tutorial from Android Testing Codelab
   https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-testing/#0

`

```
public Matcher<View> withItemText(final String itemText) {
        checkArgument(!TextUtils.isEmpty(itemText),"cannot be null");
        return new TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {
            @Override
            protected boolean matchesSafely(View item) {
                return allOf(isDescendantOfA(isAssignableFrom(RecyclerView.class)),withText(itemText)).matches(item);
            }

            @Override
            public void describeTo(Description description) {
                description.appendText("is descendant of a RecyclerView with text" + itemText);
            }
        };
    }
```

`

And then, do this:

```
onView(withItemText("what")).perform(click());
```

Comment: The first way is the best for me, because it doen't require espresso-contrib, that broke my applications' build.

Answer (score 2):

You needn't to add "testing-support-lib", neither "espresso:espresso-core". They are transitive added when "espresso:espresso-contrib" is added.

**build.grade**

```
dependencies {
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.3'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.3'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2'
}
```

**Usage**:

```
onView(withId(R.id.recyclerView)).perform(
            RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition(0, click()));
```

Answer (score 1):

I followed @Gabor's answer but when I included the libraries, I **hit the dex limit!**

So, I removed the libraries, added this `getInstrumentation().waitForIdleSync();` and then just called `onView(withId...))...`

Works perfectly.

In your case you will have multiple image views with the same ID so you will have to figure out something on how you can select the particular list item.

Answer (score 1):

As I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40366044/how-to-let-espresso-click-a-specific-recyclerview-item) you can implement your custom `RecyclerView` matcher. Let's assume you have `RecyclerView` where each element has subject you wonna match:

```
public static Matcher<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> withItemSubject(final String subject) {
    Checks.checkNotNull(subject);
    return new BoundedMatcher<RecyclerView.ViewHolder, MyCustomViewHolder>(
            MyCustomViewHolder.class) {

        @Override
        protected boolean matchesSafely(MyCustomViewHolder viewHolder) {
            TextView subjectTextView = (TextView)viewHolder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.subject_text_view_id);

            return ((subject.equals(subjectTextView.getText().toString())
                    && (subjectTextView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)));
        }

        @Override
        public void describeTo(Description description) {
            description.appendText("item with subject: " + subject);
        }
    };
}
```

And usage:

```
onView(withId(R.id.my_recycler_view_id)
    .perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnHolderItem(withItemSubject("My subject"), click()));
```

Basically you can match anything you want. In this example we used subject `TextView` but it can be any element inside the `RecyclerView` item.

One more thing to clarify is check for visibility `(subjectTextView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)`. We need to have it because sometimes other views inside `RecyclerView` can have the same subject but it would be with `View.GONE`. This way we avoid multiple matches of our custom matcher and target only item that actually displays our subject.

Answer (score 1):

With this code, you can scroll the recycler view to find your item withText and perform click or other action on it.

### dependencies

```
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.3.0'
```

### Code

```
@Test
public void scrollRecyclerViewAndClick() {
    onView(withId(R.id.recycler_view)).
            perform(RecyclerViewActions.
            actionOnItem(withText("specific string"), click()));
}
```