# How to click on a button within a recycler view item using espresso?

Tags: android, automated-tests, android-recyclerview, android-espresso

Just to take an example, say my recycler view(with id "list") is this Gmail Inbox

[image]

I already know `onView(withId(R.id.list)).perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition(1, click());` let's me to open the second email.

But how do I just click on the star button of the second email with espresso ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the following stackoverflow question:
It creates a ViewAction that clicks a view object, identified by id, at a specific position in the recyclerView.

[Using Espresso to click view inside RecyclerView item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28476507/using-espresso-to-click-view-inside-recyclerview-item)

Comment: What if the link is dead?