# How to access child view of recycler view in android espresso?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-espresso

I am writing Espresso unit testing for Recycler view. 
In recycler view I have text view which is clickable. I want to perform click event on text view in espresso testing. So how to access that text view?

Comment: check this link - http://stackoverflow.com/a/30338665/2798289

Answer (score 2):

You can use [RecyclerViewActions](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/contrib/RecyclerViewActions.html#actionOnItemAtPosition(int,%20android.support.test.espresso.ViewAction))

```
onView(withId(R.id.recyclerView))
    .perform(actionOnItemAtPosition(0, click()));
```

Include to Gradle:

```
dependencies {
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:testing-support-lib:0.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.0'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.0'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this, I've tested the same**

```
onView(withRecyclerView(R.id.recyclerView)
      .atPositionOnView(position, R.id.childView))
      .perform(click());
```

**Method Calling**

```
public static RecyclerViewMatcher withRecyclerView(final int recyclerViewId) {
    return new RecyclerViewMatcher(recyclerViewId);
}
```

**RecyclerViewMatcher**

```
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import org.hamcrest.Description;
import org.hamcrest.Matcher;
import org.hamcrest.TypeSafeMatcher;

public class RecyclerViewMatcher {

private final int recyclerViewId;

public RecyclerViewMatcher(int recyclerViewId) {
    this.recyclerViewId = recyclerViewId;
}

public Matcher<View> atPosition(final int position) {
    return atPositionOnView(position, -1);
}

public Matcher<View> atPositionOnView(final int position, final int targetViewId) {
    return new TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {
        Resources resources = null;
        View childView;

        public void describeTo(Description description) {
            String idDescription = Integer.toString(recyclerViewId);
            if (this.resources != null) {
                try {
                    idDescription = this.resources.getResourceName(recyclerViewId);
                } catch (Resources.NotFoundException var4) {
                    idDescription = String.format("%s (resource name not found)", recyclerViewId);
                }
            }
            description.appendText("with id: " + idDescription);
        }

        public boolean matchesSafely(View view) {
            this.resources = view.getResources();
            if (childView == null) {
                RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.getRootView().findViewById(recyclerViewId);

                if (recyclerView != null && recyclerView.getId() == recyclerViewId) {
                    RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position);

                    if (viewHolder != null) {
                        childView = viewHolder.itemView;
                    }
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            if (targetViewId == -1) {
                return view == childView;
            } else {
                View targetView = childView.findViewById(targetViewId);
                return view == targetView;
            }
        }
    };
}
```