# Click a textview in RecyclerView with Espresso

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-espresso

I have a unit test to do and I have to click on a Textview that is in the first position of a recyler view. I have this code

```
 onView(withId(R.id.recyclerViewDevices))
                .perform(actionOnItemAtPosition(0, click()));
```

but I want to click only in the textView that as the name of "CONNECT" and not in all the position. Can you help me?

Comment: I think you have to use onData and onChildView for working with lists. https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/basics/index.html#using-ondata-with-adapterview-controls-listview-gridview-

Comment: Possible duplicate of  - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28476507/using-espresso-to-click-view-inside-recyclerview-item

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with a custom ViewAction

```
private class ClickOnTextView implements ViewAction {

    ViewAction click = click();
    int textViewId;

    public ClickOnTextView(int textViewId) {
        this.textViewId = textViewId;
    }

    @Override
    public Matcher<View> getConstraints() {
        return click.getConstraints();

    }

    @Override
    public String getDescription() {
        return " click on TextView with id: " + textViewId;
    }

    @Override
    public void perform(UiController uiController, View view) {
        click.perform(uiController, view.findViewById(textViewId));
    }
}
```

Then change your code to:

```
onView(withId(R.id.recyclerViewDevices)).perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition(0, new ClickOnTextView(R.id.CONNECT)));
```

Comment: ViewAction click = click(); this line gives an error on click();

Comment: Add to your imports: ```import static android.support.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.click;```

Comment: it does not connect. It keeps in the activity and does nothing :S

Comment: try the solution described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32788964/1401164) then

Comment: do you want to click on the textview with **id** "connect" or with **text** "connect"?

Comment: with text connect

Answer (score 0):

Use this piece of code:

```
public static ViewAction clickChildViewWithId(final int id) {
    return new ViewAction() {
        @Override
        public Matcher<View> getConstraints() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public String getDescription() {
            return "Click on a child view with specified id.";
        }

        @Override
        public void perform(UiController uiController, View view) {
            View v = view.findViewById(id);
            v.performClick();
        }
    };
}
```

and use it like this:

```
onView(allOf(withId(R.id.ID_OF_RECYCLERVIEW), isDisplayed())).perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition(POSITION_IN_RECYCLERVIEW, clickChildViewWithId(R.id.ID_OF_TEXTVIEW)));
```