# Espresso - How to click on a random RecyclerView item?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-testing, android-espresso

There are a few posts that show how can you click a certain **fixed** item in the RecyclerView with Espresso, like:

[How to click on an item inside a RecyclerView in Espresso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27396583/how-to-click-on-an-item-inside-a-recyclerview-in-espresso)

[Using Espresso to click view inside RecyclerView item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28476507/using-espresso-to-click-view-inside-recyclerview-item)

---

**Example:**

```
//Change the 0 with any other number, will be the position of the item clicked.
onView(withId(R.id.a_main_recycler))
                .perform(RecyclerViewActions
                        .actionOnItemAtPosition(0, click()));
```

---

But, what if you want to click on a **random** item in the RecyclerView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `getActivity()` method of [ActivityTestRule](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/rule/ActivityTestRule.html#getActivity()).

You will be able to use `findViewById()` (as in any other context) and *handle* the RecyclerView instance.

---

**Example:**

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class RandomBehaviorTest {

    //This rule provides functional testing of a single activity.
    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mActivityRule =
            new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class);

    @Test
    public void clickRandomItem() {
        //Magic happening
        int x = getRandomRecyclerPosition(R.id.a_main_recycler);

        onView(withId(R.id.a_main_recycler))
                .perform(RecyclerViewActions
                        .actionOnItemAtPosition(x, click()));
    }

    private int getRandomRecyclerPosition(int recyclerId) {
        Random ran = new Random();
        //Get the actual drawn RecyclerView 
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) mActivityRule
                .getActivity().findViewById(recyclerId);

        //If the RecyclerView exists, get the item count from the adapter
        int n = (recyclerView == null)
                ? 1
                : recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount();

        //Return a random number from 0 (inclusive) to adapter.itemCount() (exclusive) 
        return ran.nextInt(n);
    }

}
```

Comment: In your example recyclerView always is null

Comment: It seems espresso team is against this option: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=isihPOY2vS4&feature=youtu.be&t=268