# How to click on every item in a RecyclerView with Android Espresso

Tags: android, android-testing, android-espresso

There are posts on how to click on a certain item in a RecyclerView at whatever position you input, but is there a way to click on all the views, especially given the fact that I may not know how many views there will be in the Recycler View.

I thought of getting the number of items in the RecyclerView like [in this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35306033/espresso-how-to-click-on-a-random-recyclerview-item) but it involves getting the actual RecyclerView from the activity which sometimes is not possible.

I've also seen a block of code like:

```
public static class RecyclerViewItemCountAssertion implements ViewAssertion { private final int expectedCount;

    public RecyclerViewItemCountAssertion(int expectedCount) {
        this.expectedCount = expectedCount;
    }

    @Override
    public void check(View view, NoMatchingViewException noViewFoundException) {
        if (noViewFoundException != null) {
            throw noViewFoundException;
        }

        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view;
        RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = recyclerView.getAdapter();
        assertThat(adapter.getItemCount(), is(expectedCount));
    }
}
```

But i'm unsure of how to manipulate to get the count

Answer (score 1):

So simply in your test:

```
final View viewById = activityTestRule.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.your_recycler_view_id);
final RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) viewById;
final RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = recyclerView.getAdapter();
final int itemsCount = adapter.getItemCount();
```

So you can iterate through from `0` to `itemsCount-1`

You can use this class to get recycler view element at position (in your case `0 to itemsCount-1`)

```
public class RecyclerViewMatcher {
private final int recyclerViewId;

public RecyclerViewMatcher(int recyclerViewId) {
    this.recyclerViewId = recyclerViewId;
}

public Matcher<View> atPosition(final int position) {
    return atPositionOnView(position, -1);
}

public Matcher<View> atPositionOnView(final int position, final int targetViewId) {

    return new TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {
        Resources resources = null;
        View childView;

        public void describeTo(Description description) {
            String idDescription = Integer.toString(recyclerViewId);
            if (this.resources != null) {
                try {
                    idDescription = this.resources.getResourceName(recyclerViewId);
                } catch (Resources.NotFoundException var4) {
                    idDescription = String.format("%s (resource name not found)", recyclerViewId);
                }
            }

            description.appendText("with id: " + idDescription);
        }

        public boolean matchesSafely(View view) {

            this.resources = view.getResources();

            if (childView == null) {
                RecyclerView recyclerView =
                        (RecyclerView) view.getRootView().findViewById(recyclerViewId);
                if (recyclerView != null && recyclerView.getId() == recyclerViewId) {
                    childView = recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position).itemView;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            if (targetViewId == -1) {
                return view == childView;
            } else {
                View targetView = childView.findViewById(targetViewId);
                return view == targetView;
            }
        }
    };
}}
```

and use this class like this:

```
onView(new RecyclerViewMatcher(R.id.your_recycler_view_id)
            .atPositionOnView(0, R.id.your_item_body))
            .perform(click());
```

So finally you are able to click all items in your recyclerview. I hope it would help. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking out loud here, but a couple of things I would try are: 
a- Check to see if there is any way to put this in the ViewHolder/RecyclerView Adapter. That really depends on *when* you want to trigger the click on all items so I'm guessing it won't work for you.
b- Try a while loop with a try/catch for getting the item. This doesn't sound like a good idea from a software engineering best practices perspective, but it should work if your goal is just to get something working. 
c- If you can't get the recycler view itself, is there some way you can access the arraylist (or whatever) you used to populate the recyclerView itself?

Some questions: 
1- In what cases is it not possible for you to get the actual recycler view? And if you can't get it, then how will you trigger its onclick anyway? 
2- Could you maybe share your code and where you need to do this?

*disclaimer: I'm a bit new to android development, but I hope this helps.*

Answer (score 0):

To be thread safe you should use custom view action something like

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class XXXXActivityTest {

int count=0;

@Test
public void xxxxxxx() throws Exception {
    onView(allOf(withId(R.id.drawer_list))).perform(new ViewAction() {
        @Override
        public Matcher<View> getConstraints() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public String getDescription() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void perform(UiController uiController, View view) {
            count=((ListView)view).getAdapter().getCount();
        }
    });

}
}
```

then you can iterate with

```
onView(new RecyclerViewMatcher(R.id.drawer_list)
        .atPositionOnView(0, R.id.your_item_body))
        .perform(click());
assertThat(.......) for all items
```