# Espresso - how to find a specific item in a recycler view (order is random)

Tags: android, android-espresso

I'm wondering how I would be able to find a specific item in a recycler view where the order of items is randomized each run.

Let's assume I have 4 items in the recycler view, each represented by the same type of view holder with a text view in it. A unique title is applied to each view holder/item. For this example let's say the titles are, for simplicity's sake, "A", "B", "C", and "D".

How would I find the position (and then click) item "A" if the order is randomized? I know if the order does not change I could the scrollToPosition RecyclerViewInteraction action, but in this case the order can and will change.

Any thoughts?

Comment: don't randomize the items, or rather, randomize then in a predictable fashion. You can use the same seed each time in your random generator to make sure the items are where you look for them.

Comment: Assume that the order of the items cannot be controlled by the developer.  In an ideal world, yes, a set order (or a predictable order as you suggest) is ideal. For this scenario it's not possible.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I was able to get this to work doing the following:

```
Matcher<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> matcher = CustomMatcher.withTitle("A");
onView((withId(R.id.recycler_view))).perform(scrollToHolder(matcher), actionOnHolderItem(matcher, click()));
```

Where `CustomMatcher.withTitle` is:

```
    public static Matcher<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> withTitle(final String title)
{
    return new BoundedMatcher<RecyclerView.ViewHolder, CustomListAdapter.ItemViewHolder>(CustomListAdapter.ItemViewHolder.class)
    {
        @Override
        protected boolean matchesSafely(CustomListAdapter.ItemViewHolder item)
        {
            return item.mTitleView.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(title);
        }

        @Override
        public void describeTo(Description description)
        {
            description.appendText("view holder with title: " + title);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: This only works because `CustomListAdapter.ItemViewHolder` exposes `mTitleView` as a public field. If you only do this for testing then you are leaking test code into the app.

Answer (score 11):

You don't need a custom matcher for this, just use this

```java
onView(withId(R.id.recycler_id)).perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItem(hasDescendant(withText("A")), click()));
```

and add espresso-contrib dependency

```
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:<espressso-version>'
```

Or if you're using AndroidX

```
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:<espressso-version>'
```

Comment: this will not work when the item is not in view

Comment: It will scroll to find the item first then click it

Comment: Does not scroll for me.

Comment: I honestly can't believe this was the only place I found this information. Why isn't this the default way to test lists :(

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old question, while @Zach's answer is a good start, and help me in my answer, we have a recycler view with loads of different types of ViewHolders with different Ids for the texts the answer did not fully suit our use case.

What I ended up doing was using a slightly different matcher, which does not reference any specific Ids or variables:

```
fun withText(title: String) = object : BoundedMatcher<View, View>(View::class.java) {
    override fun describeTo(description: Description?) {
        description?.appendText("Searching for title with: $title")
    }

    override fun matchesSafely(item: View?): Boolean {
        val views = ArrayList<View>()
        item?.findViewsWithText(views, title, View.FIND_VIEWS_WITH_TEXT)

        return when {
            views.size == 1 -> true
            else -> false
        }
    }
}
```

And usage:

```
RecyclerViewActions.scrollTo<ViewHolder>(withText("Some unique text I'm looking for")
```

Comment: Very helpful. I couldn't figure out how to find an item by text.

Answer (score -2):

Use `Espresso.onData` using a custom view matcher. [Google example](https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/advanced/#matching-data-using-ondata-and-a-custom-viewmatcher)

I have used something that could be adapted like this for your case:

```
onData(new BaseMatcher<String>() {
        @Override
        public void describeTo(Description description) {
            // what?
            description.appendText("Matches A");
        }

        @Override
        public boolean matches(Object item) {
            return item instanceof String && ((String) item).equals("A");
        }
    }).perform(click());
```

You can replace `String` by whatever your model type is if it is more complex than that, and also use the built-in matchers if it is simple (this case can be simplified by `onData(is("A")).perform(click())`).

Comment: Sounds like a good approach, but I'm getting an error trying to use this: `android.support.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: is assignable from class: class android.widget.AdapterView`

Comment: Ah, I don't think onData can be used for recycler views, is that correct?

Comment: right. I would have thought it could have worked. there this, though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27396583/how-to-click-on-an-item-inside-a-recyclerview-in-espresso

Comment: Thanks, this led me to figuring out a way to handle it... will post in an answer now!