# How to let Espresso click a specific RecyclerView item?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-espresso, android-espresso-recorder

I am trying to write an instrumentation test with *Espresso* for my Android app which uses a `RecyclerView`. Here is the main layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/grid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

... and the item view layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This means there are a couple of `TextViews` on the screen which all have the `label` id. I am trying to click a specific label. I tried to let Espresso test recorder generate the code:

```
onView(allOf(withId(R.id.grid), isDisplayed()))
    .perform(actionOnItemAtPosition(5, click()));
```

I rather want to to something like:

```
// Not working
onView(allOf(withId(R.id.grid), isDisplayed()))
    .perform(actionOnItem(withText("Foobar"), click()));
```

---

## Readings

I read quite a bit about the topic but still cannot figure out how to test a `RecyclerView` item based on its content **not** based on its position index.

- [Advanced Android Espresso - Slide on RecyclerViewActions](http://chiuki.github.io/advanced-android-espresso/#/32) (Chiu-Ki Chan)
- [RecyclerView and espresso, a complicated story](https://medium.com/@_rpiel/recyclerview-and-espresso-a-complicated-story-3f6f4179652e#.2dnr2sbnl) (Patrick Bacon, Jul 18, 2015)
- [Espresso – Testing RecyclerViews at Specific Positions](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/04/15/espresso-testing-recyclerviews/) (Romain Piel, April 15, 2016)

Answer (score 3):

You can implement your custom `RecyclerView` matcher. Let's assume you have `RecyclerView` where each element has subject you want to match:

```
public static Matcher<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> withItemSubject(final String subject) {
    Checks.checkNotNull(subject);
    return new BoundedMatcher<RecyclerView.ViewHolder, MyCustomViewHolder>(
            MyCustomViewHolder.class) {

        @Override
        protected boolean matchesSafely(MyCustomViewHolder viewHolder) {
            TextView subjectTextView = (TextView)viewHolder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.subject_text_view_id);

            return ((subject.equals(subjectTextView.getText().toString())
                    && (subjectTextView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)));
        }

        @Override
        public void describeTo(Description description) {
            description.appendText("item with subject: " + subject);
        }
    };
}
```

And usage:

```
onView(withId(R.id.my_recycler_view_id)
    .perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnHolderItem(withItemSubject("My subject"), click()));
```

Basically you can match anything you want. In this example we used subject `TextView` but it can be any element inside the `RecyclerView` item.

One more thing to clarify is check for visibility `(subjectTextView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)`. We need to have it because sometimes other views inside `RecyclerView` can have the same subject but it would be with `View.GONE`. This way we avoid multiple matches of our custom matcher and target only item that actually displays our subject.

Comment: Anyone know what the function of that appendText is?

Comment: In this way you customise your error description in case of failure.

Answer (score 1):

`actionOnItem()` matches against the itemView of the ViewHolder. In this case, the TextView is wrapped in the RelativeLayout, so you need to update the Matcher to account for it.

```
onView(allOf(withId(R.id.grid), isDisplayed()))
    .perform(actionOnItem(withChild(withText("Foobar")), click()));
```

You can also use [hasDescendant()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/matcher/ViewMatchers.html#hasDescendant(org.hamcrest.Matcher%3Candroid.view.View%3E)) to wrap your matcher is the case of a more complex nesting.

Comment: Does `hasDescendant()` automatically traverse the hierarchy levels regardless of how deep views are nested? Or do I have to use `hasDescendant(hasDescendant(...))`?

Comment: Yup, `hasDescendant()` will handle the entire view hierarchy from the root that is in `onView()` part. In case of recyclerview actions, the root is the `itemView`.