# Gradle sync failed: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: build.gradle, android-studio-3.0

I am using android studio 3.0, and i  downloaded a project from http://www.androidbootstrap.com and when i import that project it gives me error as "Gradle sync failed: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified".
This type of question and respective answers already posted but non of them solve my problem due to this reason i am posting this question please understand this.

the Gradle Script>build.gradle is:

```html
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

and app\build.gradle is:

```html
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.19.2'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://github.com/donnfelker/mvn-repo/raw/master/' }
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

def computeVersionCode() {

    if (System.env.BUILD_NUMBER) {              // Check if there is a system build number.
        return "$System.env.BUILD_NUMBER".toInteger()
    } else if (System.env.CIRCLE_BUILD_NUM) {   // Check to see if this is built on circle CI
        return "$System.env.CIRCLE_BUILD_NUM".toInteger()
    } else {
        return 1                                // if none is found, default to 1.
    }
}

def computeVersionName() {
    return "1." + computeVersionCode()
}

//noinspection GroovyUnusedAssignment
def gitSha = 'git rev-parse --short HEAD'.execute([], project.rootDir).text.trim()


android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 23

        versionCode computeVersionCode()
        versionName computeVersionName()

        // Enable this if you want to use Build.GIT_SHA in your code somewhere.
        // This will give you the last GIT_SHA that was committed
        // buildConfigField "String", "GIT_SHA", "\"${gitSha}\""



        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }

    packagingOptions {
        // Exclude file to avoid
        // Error: Duplicate files during packaging of APK
        exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
    }

     signingConfigs {
         // Uncomment and set values and then this will work
//         release {
//             storeFile file(System.getenv('ANDROID_KEYSTORE_PATH'))
//             storePassword System.getenv('ANDROID_STORE_PASS')
//             keyAlias System.getenv('ANDROID_KEY_ALIAS')
//             keyPassword System.getenv('ANDROID_KEY_PASS')
//         }
     }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
            minifyEnabled false
            // zipAlign false // this is default for debug
        }
        release {
            // minifyEnabled true
            // proguardFile '..\proguard.cfg'
            // signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            // zipAlign true // this is default for release
            // testPackageName 'example.com.tests'
            // testInstrumentationRunner 'android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner' // this is the default
        }
    }

}

dependencies {

    // Android Support Libs
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'

    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'

    // Dependency Injection
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0'


    // View Injection
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'

    // Logging
    compile 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:3.0.2'

    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:viewpagerindicator:2.4.1'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'

    // Event Bus
    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.5'

    // Image Loading
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:1.1.1'

    // HTTP
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.5.1'


    // Fabric/Crashlytics
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.2.3@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }

    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.4'
    // Set this dependency to use JUnit 4 rules
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.4'
    // Set this dependency to build and run Espresso tests
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1'
    // Contrib
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.1') {
        // http://stackoverflow.com/a/30931887/5210
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
    }
    // Set this dependency to build and run UI Automator tests
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.2'

    androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5'

    apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0'
    provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try instead proxy settings of your project.

Comment: sorry but I am not understanding what you want to say??

Comment: sometimes proxy server causes the problem if you are working in a restricted environment and the access of resources are restricted then proxy server is a good option.