# Gradle Duplicate Entry: java.util.zip.ZipException

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, zendesk

I integrated the Zendesk mobile sdk through its maven repository into my project and it wouldn't build anymore. It has some kind of a clash with picasso library that i am using. I get this error during the build:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/squareup/picasso/Action$RequestWeakReference.class
```

I ran `../gradlew dependencies` on the app folder and this is what i found under zendesk module:

```
\--- com.zendesk:sdk:1.0.0.1
     +--- com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.4.1
     |    \--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4
     +--- com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2
     +--- com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.+ -> 21.0.3 (*)
     \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.+ -> 21.0.3 (*)
```

So zendesk is also using picasso but a different version than what i have in my project. I tried excluding picasso from zendesk like this:

```
compile (group: 'com.zendesk', name: 'sdk', version: '1.0.0.1'){
            exclude group: 'com.squareup.picasso'
        }
```

but this causes runtime exceptions in other components of the app. I get a NoDefFoundError for a class totally unrelated to the libraries.
Does any one have any idea how to get around this problem ?

Comment: Would you be able to post the complete "build.gradle" file that you are using?  Thanks.

Answer (score 27):

When you added the `com.android.support:multidex` dependency you actually added some dependencies that collide with other dependencies.

I solved it by:
---------------
1.  searching for the class, in you case the "RequestWeakReference.class" (in AndroidStudio just hit Ctrl+N on Windows or CMD-O on Mac)
2. See which jar contains it - Android Studio will write it in the popup.
3. Exclude it from all builds, for example:

```
android {
     configurations{
        all*.exclude module: 'servlet-api'
    }
}
```

Comment: is there any right solution.i am getting same problem java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/gson/annotations/Expose.class  please help me. i put like this  configurations{ all*.exclude module: 'gson-2.1' }

Comment: @RamBabuPudari i am facing same issue with Expose.class. Have you find any solution?

Comment: @Tomer This worked for me. I was facing similar issue when using volley in Android Studio in one of my projects.

Comment: @SherazAhmadKhilji I am also facing the issue with Volley itself, Could you tell me what did you did exactly?

Comment: @PravinsinghWaghela i enabled multidex in my `build.gradle` and i played around with the gradle file until i got it to work.

Comment: i m also facing same issue but i m only using add mobs in my app

Comment: @Rohan im in the same sh*t with the Expose.class. How did you manage, man?

Comment: This is time saver solution. After 8 hours search end here.  If this code not working just comment the conflict dependency.  For ex: Dependency A in your library jar Comment/delete the Dependency A from your project