# java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:

Tags: android, android-studio

Error:Execution failed for task ':driverMaticsApp:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.

> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/flurry/sdk/jv$a.class

I removed old flurry and add latest version of flurry then it shows an error of duplicate entry:

Please help...

here is my build.gradle :-

```
    android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
packagingOptions{
    exclude("META.INF/LICENSE.txt")
    exclude("META.INF/README.txt")
}

lintOptions{
    checkReleaseBuilds false
    abortOnError false
}
defaultConfig {
    compileOptions.encoding = 'windows-1251'
    applicationId "com.appname.android"
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 17
    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
}
dexOptions {
    incremental false
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
}

dependencies { 
compile project(':facebookSDK') 
compile fileTree(dir:'libs',include:'*.jar')
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3' 
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2' 
compile 'org.twitter4j:twitter4j-core:4.0.4' 
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3' 
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:7.5.0' 
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.5.0' 
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.5.0'

}
```

Comment: clean and rebuild the project

Comment: check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28168063/gradle-duplicate-entry-java-util-zip-zipexception?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: Can you post all of your `build.gradle` files?

Comment: Post your `build.gradle.`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1'
 compile('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1') { exclude module:'support-v4' } 
compile ('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.2.0') { exclude module: 'support-v4' }

Comment: Here is my build.gradle file.

Comment: Do not post this as an answer. Post it in your question.