# i'm getting this error when trying to generate a signed apk

Tags: android, release

I'm getting this error when trying to generate a signed apk:

> Error:Execution failed for task 
>   :app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'.
>    com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/android/volley/AuthFailureError.class

**Build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

compileSdkVersion 23

buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.raz.base"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled = true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
 }
}

dependencies {

compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:7.5.0'

compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.+'

compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'

compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
```

}

Comment: Use MultiDex and try check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37132040/duplicate-entry-com-android-volley-authfailureerror-class-while-compiling-proje)?

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33209631/errorexecution-failed-for-task-apptransformclasseswithjarmergingfordebug