# How can solve Duplicate jar entry [com/android/volley/R.class] in Release build?

Tags: java, android, jar, dependencies, android-volley

I am getting an error when generate apk in release mode. The error is **Duplicate jar entry [com/android/volley/R.class]**. I knew that the issue is caused because I am using an external jar file which contains Volley & I am using Volley in my project. I would like to know how I can exclude the dependency from the external jar files.

It happen when the condition

> minifiedEnabled is true

I saw similar questions but none of them helped me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43115201/3395198

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I already tried it. But it is excluding the volley of my application. I need to exclude the volley from jar file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The excluse functions are not worked. SO then we fixed the issue by replace the **JAR** library with **AAR**

Answer (score 1):

Try marking your volley dependency as compileOnly

`compileOnly 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'`