# How to solve Error: ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.?

Tags: android-studio, plugins, runtime-error, qr-code

I have been tried all solutions, which are all related my question in the stack overflow and google too. i fed up with this error as long.

Am using lib for scanning qr code which is added in the below gradle file, so upon i add this lib only am getting the following error

this is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.inspirenetz.app.inpartner"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "com.google.android.apps.common.testing.testrunner.GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }

    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.json:json:20140107'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.4'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.4.1'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.4.1'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.4.1'
    compile group: 'cz.msebera.android' , name: 'httpclient', version: '4.4.1.1'

    compile 'com.embarkmobile:zxing-android-minimal:2.0.0@aar'
    compile 'com.embarkmobile:zxing-android-integration:2.0.0@aar'
    compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'

    // Avoid the 64K limit, Multidex support for Android 5.0 and higher
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

    compile files('libs/mswiperAPIVer2.0.jar')

    repositories { mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://raw.github.com/embarkmobile/zxing-android-minimal/mvn-repo/maven-repository/" }
    }

}
```

Here hell of the error killing me

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
```

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/zxing/aztec/AztecDetectorResult.class

Would really appreciated some expected solution will solve many related questions too

Thanks in advance.!

Comment: This is in no way an answer to your problem but..  If the problem lies in `zxing`, then you can always switch to e.g. the `google.vision.barcode` instead. It's the Google default barcode library shipped in the support lib. Probably [this post](https://www.varvet.com/blog/android-qr-code-reader-made-easy/) will get you up and running with a QR reader in no time!

Comment: oh my goodness at last i got reply on this question thanks.!, but may i know are you using this code and about its performance

Comment: actually the above lib also working well for me one project  but upon i try to add another project its throws this error

Comment: Was that a question in your first reply...? And yeah, or course `zxing` should work, I'm not sure what your error is due to.

Comment: your post also not help same error from long days i can't solve  this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last i found the solution of my question [from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28168063/gradle-duplicate-entry-java-util-zip-zipexception) after long days back. and i have changed the lib for QR/Bar code scanner as well.

**Problem:** I using the jar externally name as `core.jar`. so, the `AztecDetectorResult.class` already contain in `core.jar` and in my scanner lib dependency `core-3.2.1` too. so its throws the duplicate entry error as below.

```
com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: 
java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/zxing/aztec/AztecDetectorResult.class
```

**Solution:** I tried to exclude it from the core.jar as below.

```
configurations{
    all*.exclude module: 'core'
}
```

And i have changed my new lib too [ZXing Android Embedded](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/) for efficient QR/Bar code scanner.

Now its working like charm.!

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**

I find out I am not only contain core.jar ,but also compile zxing related remote repository, so it result in the error above.

**Solution:**

The solution is deleting the core.jar file then it's ok.

Comment: I'm not quite sure **what** this is; it appears to be both an unrelated question and the solution to the unrelated question. You should write this as a new question (possibly linking to this question as reference), and then answer with your solution. You can find more information about self-answering questions [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).