# com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/annotation/CallSuper.class?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-multidex

**I tried all solutions available in stackoverflow. But none of them are working.**
this is my dependencies in build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1')
compile ('com.android.support:design:23.1.1')
compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0')
compile files('libs/applovin-6.1.4.jar')
compile files('libs/appodeal-1.13.10.jar')
compile files('libs/chartboost-6.0.2.jar')
compile files('libs/inmobi-5.0.1.jar')
compile files('libs/my-target-4.1.2.jar')
compile files('libs/unity-ads-1.4.7.jar')
compile files('libs/yandex-metrica-android-2.00.jar')
compile ('com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1')
```

}

when I try to run I get this error:
    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/annotation/CallSuper.class

I have enabled multidex and included in manifest. I checked using ctrl+N, CallSuper is found in two jar files: **1) android.support.annotations** and **2) support-v4**.
Please help me out in eliminating this error. Thank You.

Comment: Have you tried the solution described here? http://stackoverflow.com/a/29127909/888881

Answer (score 0):

when we add 
`compile ('com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1')` ,then something else will be added,so i solved my problem by changing

> `compile ('com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1')`

to

> `androidTestCompile('com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1') {
>           exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
>       }`