# android java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, library-project

I have a project named **MyProject**.

It includes 2 library projects ***abc.aar*** and ***xyz.aar***.

These both library projects uses and have one common jar **dummy.jar** `(package name: com.example.dummy).`

When I include both library projects, it gives me

```
    android java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry com/example/dummy/DummyClass$1.class
```

I have tried following things -

```
configurations {
    // to avoid double inclusion
    all*.exclude group: 'com.example.dummy'
}
```

and this too

```
compile (name:'abc', ext:'aar'){
    transitive = false
    exclude module: 'libs/dummy*.jar'
    exclude group: 'com.example.dummy'
    exclude module: 'com.example.dummy'
}
```

Please suggest to avoid double inclusion of dependency jar because of ***multiple dependency library project using same jar.***

My both library projects are not on any repositories.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry during packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26966843/java-util-zip-zipexception-duplicate-entry-during-packagealldebugclassesformult)

Comment: if library is in repositories  

     configurations {
        // to avoid double inclusion
        all*.exclude group: 'com.example.dummy'
    }

this solves the problem.

But my libraries are not in repositories and moreover none of the solution from that question is working for me. :(

Comment: Any luck with this?  The only solution I've found for this situation is to explode the dependency, delete the offending jar and zip it back up.  Of course then you'll also have to include the dependency locally.  The compile dependency stuff won't work because that is just used to determine what dependencies to download.  I think you may be able to do something with packagingOptions, but I've yet to get anything to work.