# Gradle build error : Duplicate entry

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-spinner

My gradle file is

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "24.0.0 rc2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.test.test"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
    classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.3'
}
}

repositories {
mavenCentral()
jcenter()
flatDir {
    dirs '../libs'
}
}



dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.guava'
}
compile ('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.4')
        {
            exclude group: 'org.apache.http.annotation.NotThreadSafe'
        }
compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r1.4.2'
compile 'com.mopub.volley:mopub-volley:1.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

And I am getting this error while compiling the application

**Error:Execution failed for task ':myapplication:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
 com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: 
java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/apache/http/annotation/NotThreadSafe.class**

Can anyone please tell me what I need to exclude from the dependency list. Or any solution for the problem ?

Comment: you are using any other library??If yes.. post that gradle too

Comment: @jankigadhiya I am using these jars 
adcolony.jar
android-support-v4.jar
AudienceNetwork.jar
InMobi-4.5.2.jar
MMSDK.jar
mopub-sdk.jar
org.apache.httpclient.jar

Comment: See [java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry during packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26966843/java-util-zip-zipexception-duplicate-entry-during-packagealldebugclassesformult)

Comment: @ViralThakker comment  `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0'` Then Clean-Rebuild .Let me inform

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya : I removed that dependency still the error is coming

Comment: use `buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"`

Comment: "buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"" Not working

Comment: org.apache.httpclient.jar. is conflicting with something. some class that is containing the same implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Take care if you have other subproject included. You can probably fix it by adding in your "**proguard-rules.pro**" the following exception :

```
-dontwarn org.apache.**
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your gradle like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "24.0.0 rc2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.test.test"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
    classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.3'
}
}

repositories {
mavenCentral()
jcenter()
flatDir {
    dirs '../libs'
}
}



dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.guava'
}
compile ('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.4')
        {
            exclude group: 'org.apache.http.annotation.NotThreadSafe'
        }
compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r1.4.2'
compile 'com.mopub.volley:mopub-volley:1.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

the `packagingOptions` will let you use duplicate classes. That means if two libraries having same class names then compiler will ignore that.

Comment: Try clean n Build after this.

Answer (score -1):

Clean project and then build again .duplicate entry error will resolve.

Comment: compile ('com.octo.android.robospice:robospice-retrofit:1.4.13') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.commons', module: 'commons-io'
}
compile 'commons-io:commons-io:1.3.2'                                                                                                                       try this viral