# Getting Error while running code, I tried MultidexEnable but didnt work

Tags: java, android

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.

> java.io.IOException: Can't write [/home/android1/Android/projects/ezeparents/app/build/intermediates/multi-dex/debug/componentClasses.jar] (Can't read [/home/android1/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore/4.3.2/31fbbff1ddbf98f3aa7377c94d33b0447c646b6e/httpcore-4.3.2.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [httpcore-4.3.2.jar:org/apache/http/annotation/NotThreadSafe.class]))

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ezeparents"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled = true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    android {

        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/ECLIPSE_.SF'
            exclude 'META-INF/ECLIPSE_.RSA'
            exclude  'org/apache/http/annotation/NotThreadSafe.class'

        }


    }


}
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'xpp3', module: 'xpp3'
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.7@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

    compile 'com.github.nguyenhoanglam:ImagePicker:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.roomorama:caldroid:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.scottyab:showhidepasswordedittext:0.8'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.1'
    compile 'me.relex:circleindicator:1.2.2@aar'
    compile 'com.hedgehog.ratingbar:app:1.1.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.fiskurgit:ChipCloud:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.3.+'
    compile 'com.kyleduo.switchbutton:library:1.4.4'
    compile 'com.getkeepsafe.taptargetview:taptargetview:1.9.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.4.2'
    compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android:4.1.0-rc1'
    compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.1.0-rc1'
    compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android-extensions:4.1.0-rc1'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.googlecode.android-query:android-query:0.24.3'
    compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.2'
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.github.nguyenhoanglam:ImagePicker:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.github.hani-momanii:SuperNova-Emoji:1.1'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.5'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: need more information. Please attach gradle build file.

Comment: I suppose you have problems with apache httpcomponens. Try to clear project and after that rerun gradle sync. Also try to check this issue(Duplicate zip entry [httpcore-4.3.2.jar:org/apache/http/annotation/NotThreadSafe.class])))

Comment: @MykhailoVoloshyn  Today i upgraded my android studio to 3.0 and thereafter I am facing this problem. I already enabled multiDexEnabled = true and also clean my project. still facing same issue while running application not while sync.

Comment: Please attach libraries name inside you lib folder

Comment: @AbuQauod i dont have any jar dependency

Comment: @vikassingh i have the same error. i appreciate if you can help to figure out. I have tried different things suggested here. it didn't worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please clear you dependencies. You have an error, because you have a lot of libraries, that have same functionality.
Also

Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.2 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.

In my opinion the problem is in

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.5'
```

This two libraries can have same classes, so you need to exclude one of them, or exclude this duplicates. 
You can try

```
android {

...


    packagingOptions {
           exclude  'org/apache/http/annotation/NotThreadSafe.class'
    }
}
```

Pretty the same topic([Gradle build error : Duplicate entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36911101/gradle-build-error-duplicate-entry))

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, but it didn't work for me. I upgrade my gradle according to your suggestion. Please check it

Comment: Work: compile ('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.4')
    {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.http.annotation.NotThreadSafe'
    }                                                                                                                        Didn't work:                                                                                       
compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'

Answer (score 0):

the above answer may also be correct, but it seems also an issue of the new google repo

add google as in below

In your root level gradle.build use below

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and in your `gradle-wrapper.properties` file change the wrapper version as below

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.2.1-all.zip
```