# android studio generate signed apk

Tags: android, gradle, build, android-gradle-plugin, apk

I need help with this:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'.
>
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
>   com/github/mikephil/charting/highlight/Highlight.class

```js
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "cqdevelopers.incrediblediet"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}



dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.github.ksoichiro:android-observablescrollview:1.6.0'
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.5'
    compile files('libs/GraphView-4.0.1.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.0'
}
```

Comment: Try and see if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26966843/java-util-zip-zipexception-duplicate-entry-during-packagealldebugclassesformult) question can help you

Comment: does GraphView also have a Highlight class? as that is what the error message is telling you that its in two areas..once in your source code and somewhere else in the deps you have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on Windows,
Ctrl + N : search your class "Highlight"

after knowing which are those two are more libraries which are causing this issue,
to find app dependency structure, execute

```
  gradlew app:dependencies
```

command to find out hierarchy and exclude one of them.