# Getting an Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I'm getting an exception in Android Studio while build project

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
>   android/support/v4/view/LayoutInflaterFactory.class

My gradle file is-

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.amt.partnerapp"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'


    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
}

dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries = false
}
   }

  dependencies {
  compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
  androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile files('libs/activation.jar')
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0"

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

`com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.0` depends on different version of support libraries than you provided. You can check it [here](http://www.methodscount.com/?lib=com.google.android.gms%3Aplay-services%3A9.2.0)
Try to exclude support dependencies from it. Like that:

```
compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.0') {
     exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
```

Comment: @Zagorski  I given the code like this. But getting same error

Comment: So that means, that something else is also depending on this. Try running `gradlew app;dependencies` from the console, and analyse the dependencies.

Comment: @Zagorski i given so much libraries in lib folder. If that causes issue

Comment: Of cource it can couse problems. If you put libraries in `lib` folder and not as gradle dependency, Gradle cannot resolve conflicts automatically. Try to add them as gradle dependencies.

Comment: @Zagorski   But some files i created as library

Comment: Do they depend on `support-v4`? This might be the problem.

Comment: @Zagorshi Yes it depend on support-v4. If i removed support-v4 it shows so much errors

Comment: Update library's `support-v4` version to 23.4.0.

Comment: And you are sure that no other library is using old version of `support-v4`?

Comment: @Zagorshi all libraries using new version . i checked. now i am geting Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/animation/AnimatorCompatHelper.class

Comment: And now, did you exclude `support-v4` from `gms` dependency? Or try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29127909/6507689