# TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/widget/ExploreByTouchHelper.class

Tags: java, android

I have got following error during Gradle build process:

> Error:Execution failed for task > ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>
> > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
> >     android/support/v4/widget/ExploreByTouchHelper.class

I have also checked dependencies:

```
release
+--- com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1
|    |              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.1.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1
|    |              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.1.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.4.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |              \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1
|    |                   \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.1.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:8.4.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |              \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1
|    |                   \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.1.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-appstate:8.4.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |              \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1
|    |                   \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.1.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.4.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |              \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1
|    |                   \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.1.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1
|    |              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.1.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1
|    |         \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.1.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:8.4.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |    |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1
|    |    |              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.1.jar
|    |    \--- com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:23.0.0
|    |         +--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.0.jar
|    |         \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1
|    |              +--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1
|    |              |    \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.1.jar
|    |              +--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:23.2.1
|    |              |    \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:23.2.1
|    |              |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1
|    |              |              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.1.jar
|    |              \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:23.2.1
|    |                   \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1
|    |                        \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.1.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:8.4.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |              \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1
|    |                   \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.1.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:8.4.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |    |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1
|    |    |              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.1.jar
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0
|    |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |         |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |         |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1
|    |         |              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.1.jar
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0
|    |              \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |                   \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |                        \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1
|    |                             \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.1.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:8.4.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |    |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1
|    |    |              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.1.jar
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:8.4.0
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |              \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |                   \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1
|    |                        \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.1.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |    |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1
|    |    |              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.1.jar
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:8.4.0
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |              \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1
|    |                   \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.1.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.4.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |              \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1
|    |                   \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.1.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |    |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1
|    |    |              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.1.jar
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |              \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |                   \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1
|    |                        \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.1.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |              \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1
|    |                   \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.1.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:8.4.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1
|    |              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.1.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:8.4.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |              \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1
|    |                   \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.1.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-panorama:8.4.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |              \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1
|    |                   \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.1.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.4.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |              \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1
|    |                   \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.1.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:8.4.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |              \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1
|    |                   \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.1.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:8.4.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |              \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1
|    |                   \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.1.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:8.4.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |    |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1
|    |    |              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.1.jar
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.4.0
|    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |    |              \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1
|    |    |                   \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.1.jar
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |              \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |                   \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1
|    |                        \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.1.jar
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:8.4.0
|         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|              \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|                   \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1
|                        \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.1.jar
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1
|    |    \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.1.jar
|    +--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:23.2.1
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:23.2.1
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1
|    |              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.1.jar
|    \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:23.2.1
|         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1
|              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.1.jar
+--- com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0
+--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:24.2.0
|    |    \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-24.2.0.jar
|    \--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:24.2.0
|         +--- LOCAL: internal_impl-24.2.0.jar
|         \--- com.android.support:support-compat:24.2.0
|              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-24.2.0.jar
\--- com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.0
```

Comment: possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26966843/java-util-zip-zipexception-duplicate-entry-during-packagealldebugclassesformult

Comment: @Vickyexpert : Sorry, but not, because after I added this snippet I got 30 new error message.
`configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open your system command prompt/terminal
-> Go to your Project folder path (root project folder )
-> Execute following command :
command :- `gradlew clean`or `./gradlew clean`

Make sure that all your gradle dependencies are of same version.
-> Example :- your appcompat and recyclerview dependencies should have same version.

-> Change your gradle dependencies to same version like :-

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
```

-> Rebuild your project and it will work fine.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to resolve this issue by using the most recent versions of appcompat and recyclerview for my compileSdkVersion.

Since my compileSdkVersion is set to 23 I changed my gradle dependencies to this:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
```

I noticed that you have mismatched versions of appcompat and recyclerview.  One of these doesn't match your compileSdkVersion.  If you open the build.gradle file you should see a warning about this.  Hope this helps.