# Android says duplicate entry, but it's not

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, admob, google-play-services

I am converting a project from Eclipse to Android Studio. It wasn't easy. I tried to put the AdMob banner and I got an error like this.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/ads/identifier/AdvertisingIdClient$zza.class

There's only 1 `AdvertisingIdClient$zza.class` file in the project.
Why am I getting this error?
I have spent many hours on this, but no clues.
Can anyone help me, please?

---

Thanks for all replies. Here's my gradle files.

app-gradle >>>>

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 13
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "sw.ko.aaaaa.bbbbb"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 9
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles 'proguard.cfg'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/activation.jar')
    compile files('libs/additionnal.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-email-1.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-net-2.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')
    compile files('libs/mail.jar')
    compile files('libs/twitter4j-core-android-2.2.5.jar')
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Another gradle file is...

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

External Libraries...

```
Android API 13 Platform
1.8
firebase-analytics-9.0.0
firebase-analytics-impl-9.0.0
firebase-common-9.0.0
firebase-core-9.0.0
firebase-iid-9.0.0
multidex-1.0.1
multidex-instrumentation-1.0.1
play-services-base-9.0.0
play-services-basement-9.0.0
play-services-tasks-9.0.0
support-v4-23.0.0
```

Comment: This is usually caused when you use two libraries which both have a shared dependency so it tries to add them both to your compiled app. See this question for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39388746/3061857

Comment: There are various SO links for the same but from my personal experience when I tried migrating it was hell. After trying for a week. I gave up. Created new Andriod Studio project and copied code from eclipse to this one where ever required.

Comment: You need to show your `build.gradle`, please.

Comment: you can check if there are any duplicate libraries in External Libraries section.

Comment: @Sourav Ganguly That's the last comment that I want to hear. TT. I already spent a whole day. I will try a little more and I may have to do as you said. T.,T

Answer (score 1):

Remove all references to Google Play Services (JAR files and other Gradle lines)

Add this one for **Admob**

```
dependencies {
    ...

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.1'
}
```

Add more dependencies for [**other Google**](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) or [**Firebase**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) services.

---

I'd prefer to do it this way to keep all versions the same.

```
ext {
    // Variables to keep libraries consistent
    googlePlayServicesVersion = '10.0.1'
}

dependencies {
    ...

    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:${googlePlayServicesVersion}"
}
```

Comment: I tried your 2nd suggestion and it worked!!!! Thank you so much. Now I have another problem which is 'java.lang.IllegalStateException: The ad size and ad unit ID must be set before loadAd is called.' Anyway, thank you again. :)

Comment: The second suggestion is a refactoring of the first. You just needed to remove `compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')` and add the others basically. You can use the checkmark next to my answer to accept it :)