# Gradle build failed for android project

Tags: android, gradle

I am building my android project with following build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.handyman.user"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.github.ronaldsmartin:Material-ViewPagerIndicator:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.github.florent37:singledateandtimepicker:1.0.8'

    // retrofit essentials
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'

    // retrofit logging
    compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.3.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp3:1.3.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.2.0'

    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.2.0'

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'

    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

but my build is failing which says

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzv$zza$zza.class
```

In my app multidex is enabled. I tried cleaning and rebuilding project multiple times without any result and tried changing firebase dependency's version to different one's but that was also useless.

Comment: Is there something in the `libs` folder?

Comment: @Egor no libs folder is empty.

Comment: Tried Building/Cleaning Project ?

Comment: Add build.gradle file from app directory to the question for us to understand the configuration.

Comment: @ShridharR.Kulkarni Ok I will include build.gradle.

Comment: @shadygoneinsane yup already build and clean multiple times.

Comment: Can you upgrade to `firebase-messaging:10.2.0`?

Comment: Rest is fine but failed to resolve this - compile 'com.github.ronaldsmartin:Material-ViewPagerIndicator:1.0.2'

Comment: @cricket_007 let me try with `firebase-messaging:10.2.0`

Comment: @cricket_007 `firebase-messaging:10.2.0` failed to resolve this version.

Comment: Also put this at the bottom - apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services

Comment: @M.Ashish you need to add this to your project's `build.gradle` `maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }`

Comment: If you have Library projects ..do check if you have same dependencies multiple times

Comment: Shouldn't. That's the latest version. https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client

Comment: @shadygoneinsane There is no `compile project`

Comment: guys I think issue was with placement of `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`. After putting it bottom of `build.gradle` everything runs fine.

Comment: Yeah i was gonna tell you this ... anyways your problem is solved :)

Comment: @darthvish Put this at the bottom - apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Comment: see this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26966843/java-util-zip-zipexception-duplicate-entry-during-packagealldebugclassesformult

Comment: Do post an answer @darthvish for this .. maybe it will help other in future :)

Comment: @shadygoneinsane ok

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to `build.gradle`.

```
android{


    configurations {
        all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }

}
```

Credits: [java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry during packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26966843/java-util-zip-zipexception-duplicate-entry-during-packagealldebugclassesformult)

Comment: you should give credit to this answer...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26966843/java-util-zip-zipexception-duplicate-entry-during-packagealldebugclassesformult

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by putting this line`apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` at the bottom of `build.gradle` rather than below `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`