# Error app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDeb

Tags: android

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayoutCompatApi21$InsetsListener.class

This Error occurs only when I run my progream belloy sdk 20 above 20 it works fine

Comment: post your `build.gradle`

Answer (score 0):

Please check this link
[java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry during packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26966843/java-util-zip-zipexception-duplicate-entry-during-packagealldebugclassesformult)
not same as your question but it can be helpful.