# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'. >

Tags: java, firebase, error-handling, duplicates, dependencies

I dont know how to resolve this error

`Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'. > java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzaac.class`

Here are my dependencies

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.1'
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.4.0'
```

}

Thank you in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26966843/java-util-zip-zipexception-duplicate-entry-during-packagealldebugclassesformult

Comment: no i checked it, it's different and didn't help me @fabfas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have twice similar libraries of following though different version;

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
```

The error message clearly says, you have duplicate entry of following;

```
com/google/android/gms/internal/zzaac.class
```

Search this class in your dependencies and make sure only one dependency included.

Comment: when i deleted one of them, nothing changed

Comment: You may included the `com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.1` or other firebase dependency as  complete package then there is no need to include the second `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.1`. Try removing the play-services then see if you get the same error.

Comment: when i did so, another error popped up after running the project

Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.internal.zzrt.zzg

@fabfas