# Error in java.util.zip.ZipException while Generating the Signed Apk :Cannot generate the signed APK due to some warning

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

**The Error I get while generating the APK**

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/database/DatabaseUtilsCompat.class
```

---

**My Gradle**
*I get this error when i want to generate the apk from Buildbox To android studio* 
        apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mestfireMedia.switchle"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        multiDexEnabled true

        ndk {
            moduleName "player_shared"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }


    }
    sourceSets.main {
        jni.srcDirs = []// <-- disable automatic ndk-build call
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'){exclude module: 'support-v4'}
    compile files('libs/dagger-1.2.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/javax.inject-1.jar')
    compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/support-v4-19.0.1.jar')
    compile ('com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1')
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26966843/java-util-zip-zipexception-duplicate-entry-during-packagealldebugclassesformult

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry during packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26966843/java-util-zip-zipexception-duplicate-entry-during-packagealldebugclassesformult)

Comment: I do that but the problem still exist