# How to solve this message gradle build error?

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

When I run my project in kitkat emulator. I got this error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':cameraview:transformClassesAndResourcesWithPrepareIntermediateJarsForDebug'.
 > java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/otaliastudios/cameraview/AspectRatio$1.class
```

Another instant run is working perfect.Anybody known about this issue.please explain.

Comment: Please read through the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26966843/java-util-zip-zipexception-duplicate-entry-during-packagealldebugclassesformult - some of them ay help you